# Oracle how to make primary key index usable from unusable?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I have table where it's primary key index got unusable due to partition merge ( I may have done it wrong).

```
select INDEX_NAME, STATUS from ALL_INDEXES WHERE TABLE_NAME = TRANSACTION' AND INDEX_NAME = 'PK_TRAN';
```

Status from above query is `N/A` (unusable)

Then I tried to drop the index

```
drop index PK_TRAN;
```

resulted following error.

```
SQL Error: ORA-02429: cannot drop index used for enforcement of unique/primary key
```

Then i tried to drop the constraint

```
alter table TRANSACTION drop constraint PK_TRAN;
```

resulted following error,

```
SQL Error: ORA-02273: this unique/primary key is referenced by some foreign keys
```

Then  i tried to drop the problematic reference constraints

```
select CONSTRAINT_NAME from all_constraints where constraint_type='R' and r_constraint_name='PK_TRAN';

alter table A drop constraint FK_1;
```

which resulted following error.

```
SQL Error: ORA-14650: operation not supported for reference-partitioned tables
```

How can i make transaction table's pk index valid(usable). Currently operation on this table fails with

```
ORA-01502: index 'PK_TRAN' or partition of such index is in unusable state
```

Comment: `N/A` is not necessarily unusable, it means the status is not available.This must be a partition index and  you looked at the wrong view. What is the result of `select INDEX_NAME,PARTITION_NAME,STATUS from user_ind_partitions where index_name='PK_TRAN';`? Try to `alter index PK_TRAN rebuild;`

Comment: Above query returns multiple records. Each for `PARTITION_NAME`. All of them have `UNUSABLE` state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### 01502, 00000, "index '%s.%s' or partition of such index is in unusable state"
>
> MERGE: 1489 RENUMBERED TO 1502
>
> **Cause:** An attempt has been made to access an index or index partition
>           that has been marked unusable by a direct load or by a DDL
>           operation.
>
> **Action:** DROP the specified index, or REBUILD the specified index, or
>           REBUILD the unusable index partition.

Now, you have to rebuild index(es) according to their type, Global or Local.

> You can rebuild global index partitions in two ways:
>
> Rebuild each partition by issuing the ALTER INDEX REBUILD PARTITION statement (you can run the rebuilds concurrently).
>
> Drop the entire global index and re-create it. This method is more efficient because the table is scanned only one time.
>
> Rebuild local indexes using either ALTER INDEX or ALTER TABLE as follows:
>
> ALTER INDEX REBUILD PARTITION/SUBPARTITION
>
> This statement rebuilds an index partition or subpartition unconditionally.
>
> ALTER TABLE MODIFY PARTITION/SUBPARTITION REBUILD UNUSABLE LOCAL INDEXES
>
> This statement finds all of the unusable indexes for the given table partition or subpartition and rebuilds them. It only rebuilds an index partition if it has been marked UNUSABLE.

**Documentation:**[About Rebuilding Index Partitions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-6FF7CB6D-CC8D-4FCD-B92E-581C9CF0BB2E.htm#VLDBG1198)

Comment: Issue was resolved using given information. Thanks JSapkota. Queries as follows `select p.index_name, p.partition_name,p.status from dba_ind_partitions p, dba_indexes i where i.index_name=p.index_name and table_name='TRANSACTION' ` to  get the index and partitions. To rebuild each partition `ALTER INDEX PK_TRAN REBUILD PARTITION {partitionName}`